# The frame is not showing in the slide that has math equation and a table

Tags: tables, beamer, math-mode

I wrote some equation in a table and the frame of the slide has disappeared.

These are the packages I use:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\mode<presentation> {

\usetheme{Madrid}

}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepgflibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{amscd}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}




\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepgflibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{amscd}
```

This is how it looks like:

[image]

This is the code

```
\begin{frame}{Analytical forms}
    
\centering
\begin{table}
 
  \begin{tabular}{l|c}

Metric & Analytical form \\
\hline
Accuracy &   \begin{math}\frac { \sum_{n=1}^{c}  \frac{tp + tn}{tp + fp + tn + fn}}{c} \end{math}  \vspace{\baselineskip}\\ 
\hline 
 Precision &  \begin{math} \frac { \sum_{n=1}^{c}\frac{tp }{tp + fp}} {c} \end{math} \\ 
 \hline
 Recall &  \begin{math} \frac { \sum_{n=1}^{c}\frac{tp }{tp + fn} }{c} \end{math}\\
  \hline
 F1 score &  (1+\beta^2)\begin{math} \frac{AP.AR }{(\beta^2.AP) + AR}\end{math}
\end{tabular}
\caption{\label{tab:widgets}  Analytical form for each evaluation metric.}
\end{table}

\end{frame}
%------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: The red number you didn't show means that you have errors.  You have to fix the errors before you can worry about the output.

Comment: (Your example gives me 20 errors on Overleaf, but there's really only one and it's on the F1 line.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @samcarter has already pointed out in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/670868/5001), the term `\beta^2` has to occur in math mode.

At any rate, my main suggestions are to streamline and simplify the "look" of the table -- in part by avoiding "multi-storey" `\frac` expressions -- and to improve the readability of the math material by employing display-style math mode in the second column. In addition, since `beamer` doesn't "do" floats such as `table` and `figure` environments, you might as well get rid of the `table` machinery and stick the table's caption -- "Analytical form of each evaluation metric" -- into the frame title.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
\mode<presentation> { \usetheme{Madrid} }

\usepackage{array} % nmw
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepgflibrary{arrows}
%\usepackage{amscd} % loaded automatically by 'amsmath' packagr
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Analytical form of each evaluation metric}
    
\centering

\begin{tabular}{@{}l >{$\displaystyle}l<{$} @{}}

Metric    & \text{Analytical form} \\
\midrule
Accuracy  &   \frac{1}{c} \biggl( \sum_{n=1}^{c}  \frac{tp + tn}{tp + fp + tn + fn} \biggr) \\ 
\addlinespace
Precision &   \frac{1}{c} \biggl( \sum_{n=1}^{c}\frac{tp }{tp + fp} \biggr)  \\ 
\addlinespace
Recall    &   \frac{1}{c} \biggl( \sum_{n=1}^{c}\frac{tp }{tp + fn} \biggr) \\
\addlinespace
F1 score  &  (1+\beta^2) \frac{AP \cdot AR }{\beta^2 \cdot AP + AR}
\end{tabular}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you so much

Answer (score 4):

The main problem is that `(1+\beta^2)` needs to be in math mode.

Some other comments about your code:

- please don't load the same package multiple times
- you don't need to load `graphicx`, `amssymb` or `amsmath`, beamer automatically loads them for you
- if your tex distribution is reasonable up to date, you don't need `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`. That's now the default

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\mode<presentation> {

\usetheme{Madrid}

}

%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{blindtext}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepgflibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{amscd}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}




%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{blindtext}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{csquotes}
%\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepgflibrary{arrows}
%\usepackage{amscd}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Analytical forms}
    
\centering
\begin{table}
 
  \begin{tabular}{l|c}

Metric & Analytical form \\
\hline
Accuracy &   \begin{math}\frac { \sum_{n=1}^{c}  \frac{tp + tn}{tp + fp + tn + fn}}{c} \end{math}  \vspace{\baselineskip}\\ 
\hline 
 Precision &  \begin{math} \frac { \sum_{n=1}^{c}\frac{tp }{tp + fp}} {c} \end{math} \\ 
 \hline
 Recall &  \begin{math} \frac { \sum_{n=1}^{c}\frac{tp }{tp + fn} }{c} \end{math}\\
  \hline
 F1 score &  \begin{math}  (1+\beta^2)\frac{AP \cdot AR }{(\beta^2 \cdot AP) + AR}\end{math}
\end{tabular}
\caption{\label{tab:widgets}  Analytical form for each evaluation metric.}
\end{table}

\end{frame}
%------------------------------------------------


\end{document}
```

[image]

---

To make your life easier, you could use the `tabularray` package for your table. This allow to automatically choose math mode for your right column and will give a bit better spacing:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\mode<presentation> {

\usetheme{Madrid}

}

%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{blindtext}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepgflibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{amscd}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}




%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{blindtext}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{csquotes}
%\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepgflibrary{arrows}
%\usepackage{amscd}


\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Analytical forms}
    
\centering
\begin{table}
 
\begin{tblr}{
  colspec={l|c},
  column{2}={mode=dmath},
  cell{1}{2}={mode=text},
  vspan=even
}
Metric & Analytical form \\
\hline
Accuracy &  \frac { \sum_{n=1}^{c}  \frac{tp + tn}{tp + fp + tn + fn}}{c} \\ 
\hline 
 Precision &  \frac { \sum_{n=1}^{c}\frac{tp }{tp + fp}} {c} \\ 
 \hline
 Recall &   \frac { \sum_{n=1}^{c}\frac{tp }{tp + fn} }{c} \\
  \hline
 F1 score &   (1+\beta^2)\frac{AP \cdot AR }{(\beta^2 \cdot AP) + AR}\\
\end{tblr}
\caption{\label{tab:widgets}  Analytical form for each evaluation metric.}
\end{table}

\end{frame}
%------------------------------------------------


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. :-) You may also want to replace the `.` (dot) particles in the final formula with `\cdot`.

Comment: @Mico Good catch! Thanks!

Comment: thank youuu so much

Comment: @kjnk You're welcome!